# How to solve the problem of accessing the storage in Laravel folder

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Faced a problem accessing the storage folder. A symbolic link was created, but when I try to access any file in the storage folder, I get an error 403 "You do not have permission to access this object. The file is not readable, or the server cannot read it." I have a second project on a local machine, everything works fine there. I tried to give 777 permissions to the storage folder, but this causes the "Permisson denied" error. I will be glad to any help!
Macos catalina

Comment: Never give 777 in production server - make sure set `chown` (find the actual user, usually it's `www-data` - check your nginx) as well as `chmod`. I usually give 755.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Granting 777 rights was an extreme measure for me, since no solution helps. I use XAMMP (Apache) and am not quite sure how to find the group user correctly

Comment: Just a friendly advice - get your toes wet with homestead :p you'll learn tons about servers

Answer (score 1):

### Laravel Permissions

first change ownership of the laravel directory to our web group.

```
sudo chown -R :www-data /var/www/laravel
```

Next we need to give the web group write privileges over our storage directory so it can write to this folder.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/laravel/storage
```

> where **laravel** is the name of the root

Comment: I use XAMMP (Apache) and am not quite sure how to find the group user correctly. when I enter the command sudo chown -R: daemon, I get an Operation not permitted error. In the XAMMP settings user is daemon and group is daemon